# Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type pow() func

Tags: c

Im programming in c VS 2013

im trying to multiplicate the a[i] num by 10 raised by (max -1 -i). when max is the size of array, and i is initialed for (max -1). im using a for loop, i--.

im using the pow() function, and therefor had to define i as a float, or a double. Maybe max too, but it doesnt give me an error.

```
int sum = 0;
float j = 0, i;
int max;

printf("Enter number of digits: ");
scanf_s("%d", &max);

int *a;
a = (int *)malloc(max * sizeof(* a));

for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the %d digt: ", i + 1);
1   scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
}

for (i = max - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
2   sum = sum + a[i]*pow(10, max -1 -i);
    j++;
}
```

When trying to compile, it gives me an error at lines 1 and 2.. pointing on [i] and saying that expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

the (max - 1 -i) b.t.w is instead of an extra variable.. im trying to minimize them

help?

Comment: Don't cast malloc. Why are you treat sizeof as a Function?

Comment: You don't have to use floats. Change `float` to `int`.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @n.m. i do have, bc the pow() func demands one of its operators to be so

Comment: @Michi what do you mean by casting

Comment: @daniel malloc() and its Family's return type are void*. In C you do not cast malloc.

Comment: @Michi i guess im not familiar with the meaning of cast in the comput science.. bc i dont understand where i did it

Comment: If you didn't already read this, read it ==>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Michi actually, when not casting, it gives an error

Comment: Did you click on the link? There is an online compiler in there. You can enter code and it will compile and run it. I copied your code and added a few necessary things and made a few changes and it was compiled and executed and worked. Do you have a question about how this system works?

Comment: "when not casting, it gives an error". That's because you are using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. C++ and C are two different languages.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as the error message says. `i` must have an integral type such as `int`. You can't use a `float` as an array index.

Comment: ok. so how can i solve this problem as  described?.. regards to the pow()

Comment: i meant, how can i use the pow() func without giving him j.. but giving him (max - 1 - i)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're already doing it with `pow(10, max -1 -i)`. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: Quit being rude. That call is fine. `int`s are automatically promoted to `float` or `double` as needed. Do you have `#include <math.h>` at the top of your source file?

Comment: for sure.. otherwise i couldnt even use that function.. any way, i cant run the prog like this.. gives an error.. did u check it urself?

Comment: Check [the link @n.m. posted](http://ideone.com/ztVbFi). That shows the program working.

Comment: Also **what error does it give?** Stop asking us what we're seeing, or telling us to go check our error menu, whatever that is. **Tell us what you're getting**, because we're not getting what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

[too long for a comment]

If you have (more or less) complex expression in one line which does not compile, distrubute it over several lines to give the compiler a chance to point you what it does not like:

For example replace

```
sum = sum + a[i]*pow(10, max -1 -i);
```

by

```
sum = 
  sum + 
    a[i] * 
      pow(
        10, 
        max 
          -1 
          -i);
```

After have fixed the bug, remove those masive new-lines.